# Use Python variable in bash command with check_output

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I would like to enter a backup plan name as input and use that variable in my bash command to get a backup plan ID. To do this, I list the backup plans and filter by the name of the backup plan. All of this to use the backup plan ID for delete a backup selection. I don't know how to put backup_plan_name variable in bash command. I use Python 3.8.

```
import boto3
from subprocess import check_output

client = boto3.client('backup')

backup_plan_name = input ("Backup Plan Name: ")

out = check_output(["aws", "backup", "list-backup-plans", "--query", "BackupPlansList[?BackupPlanName=='backup_plan_name'].BackupPlanId", "--output", "text"])
str_data = out.decode('utf-8')
data_arr=str_data.split()

bpk_plan_id= ''.join(map(str, data_arr))

response = client.list_backup_selections(
    BackupPlanId=bpk_plan_id
)

for backup in response['BackupSelectionsList']:
    SelectionId = backup['SelectionId']

    response = client.delete_backup_selection(
        BackupPlanId=bpk_plan,
        SelectionId=SelectionId
)
```

I've tried use

```
out = check_output(["aws", "backup", "list-backup-plans", "--query", "BackupPlansList[?BackupPlanName=='%s'].BackupPlanId", "--output", "text" %backup_plan_name])
```

and

```
out = check_output(["aws", "backup", "list-backup-plans", "--query", "BackupPlansList[?BackupPlanName=='{}'].BackupPlanId", "--output", "text".format(backup_plan_name)])
```

But both strategies did not work.

Without the input, just passing the backup plan name in the bash command works like a charm.

````
import boto3
from subprocess import check_output

client = boto3.client('backup')

out = check_output(["aws", "backup", "list-backup-plans", "--query", "BackupPlansList[?BackupPlanName=='backup-daily-01'].BackupPlanId", "--output", "text"])
str_data = out.decode('utf-8')
data_arr=str_data.split()

bpk_plan= ''.join(map(str, data_arr))

response = client.list_backup_selections(
    BackupPlanId=bpk_plan
)

for backup in response['BackupSelectionsList']:
    SelectionId = backup['SelectionId']

    response = client.delete_backup_selection(
        BackupPlanId=bpk_plan,
        SelectionId=SelectionId
)
```
````

Comment: why do you use AWS CLi in python if you have boto3?

Comment: @Marcin, I tried using boto3 to do the same as this command does, but I didn't find a way to get the backup plan ID by filtering by backup plan name. if you have any suggestion i would appreciate it.

Comment: " I didn't find a way " - what do you mean? Its explained in boto3 docs how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
import boto3

backup_plan = input()


client = boto3.client('backup')

response = client.list_backup_plans(
)

for i in range(len(response['BackupPlansList'])):
    if response['BackupPlansList'][i]['BackupPlanName'] == backup_plan:
        print(response['BackupPlansList'][i]['BackupPlanId'])
```

EXPLANATION:

response from list_backup_plans looks like this:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '8b95309c-505d-49bc-a78f-b303708bb91f', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Mon, 17 Jan 2022 22:12:18 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '895', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': '8b95309c-505d-49bc-a78f-b303708bb91f'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'BackupPlansList': [{'BackupPlanArn': 'arn:aws:backup:us-east-1:352178156740:backup-plan:aws/efs/73d922fb-9312-3a70-99c3-e69367f9fdad', 'BackupPlanId': 'aws/efs/73d922fb-9312-3a70-99c3-e69367f9fdad', 'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 2, 10, 42, 57, 180000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'VersionId': 'MzlkY2Y4NGUtYjNjNy00NTkxLTg2ZjgtYmU1ZWFhN2EwMTg3', 'BackupPlanName': 'aws/efs/automatic-backup-plan', 'CreatorRequestId': 'aws/efs/automatic-backup-352178156740-us-east-1', 'LastExecutionDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 17, 11, 1, 5, 164000, tzinfo=tzlocal())}, {'BackupPlanArn': 'arn:aws:backup:us-east-1:352178156740:backup-plan:b18bb677-d939-49c2-b56f-583b3a43cf88', 'BackupPlanId': 'b18bb677-d939-49c2-b56f-583b3a43cf88', 'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 18, 4, 10, 42, 150000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'VersionId': 'MzhmZDRiOTQtZDA5My00NzQwLWEyMzYtOGYwODg1NzJiMWI4', 'BackupPlanName': 'fsdfsdf'}]}
```

To be simple it's just:

```
response = {'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

And the second key is 'BackupPlansList' and it looks like this:

```
{'BackupPlanArn': 'arn:aws:backup:us-east-1:352178156740:backup-plan:b18bb677-d939-49c2-b56f-583b3a43cf88', 'BackupPlanId': 'b18bb677-d939-49c2-b56f-583b3a43cf88', 'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 18, 4, 10, 
42, 150000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'VersionId': 'MzhmZDRiOTQtZDA5My00NzQwLWEyMzYtOGYwODg1NzJiMWI4', 'BackupPlanName': 'fsdfsdf'}
```

it's a list that list all backup plans and each element in this list is dictionary(ref to list_bucket response) so then we can select 'BackupPlanName' and then using condition compare our pasted name and all backup plan names in aws account. And if they are the same we print out BackupPlanId

You can ask questions if any details are not clear